# Alert user to navigate less in browser window

Tags: javascript, events

I am creating an online exam platform, so I don't want the user to navigate and close the browser. I have used an `onblur` event and visibility api. Both have limitations.

For example, `onblur` triggers even when the window is open and the user clicks on empty space in toolbar of the computer. The visibility api only works if the browser window is minimized. It's not applicable if it is overlapped by another window.

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        if (document.hidden) {
            alert('blur');
        } else {
            console.log("Browser tab is visible")
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: You can't force a client to not navigate new tabs or multiple browsers and you can't force your page to appear if the client attempt(s) to do any of those. This would be a big problem if possible as this could be used for malicious reasons and force people to never leave/close a web page. Maybe display a message explaining if the client leaves or opens a new page while taking the exam that will result in a exam forfeit.

Comment: Iam not forcing the the client to not navigate i just want to indicate him that he have navigated

Comment: I didn't say you had those intentions but what you are asking for could be used for that exact reason hence my doubt of your expectations being doubtful. If you want to notify the client of navigating it would appear your current attempt does that... maybe combine then both together...